# logic in AND statements

Tags: sql, postgresql, operator-precedence

I have this query that pulls data that I can use for some analysis:

---

```
SELECT   distinct egauge_analyze_2.dataid,     
date_trunc('hour', egauge_analyze_2.timestamp_localtime)::time AS HOUR, 
avg(egauge_analyze_2.use) AS USE   

FROM   dev.egauge_analyze_2

WHERE egauge_analyze_2.timestamp_localtime BETWEEN
       '2012-07-16 00:00:00' AND '2012-08-17 23:59:59' 

AND egauge_analyze_2.use IS NOT NULL

-- AND use > 0

GROUP BY 1,2 
ORDER BY 1,2
```

---

When I use it with the above (as-is) it gives me good data and throws out any dataids (and all their data) that have null values anytime, when I add the extra constraint of use > 0, it stops throwing out dataids will null values.

The data consist of dataids (a value for a unique device), a timestamp, and a USE (power draw of that device at that time) - I am trying to get seasonal profiles for the devices, but throw out whole devices that given null or erroneous (negative) data.

I would like it to throw out all dataids (and all their data) for any value of use that is null or <= 0. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a little hard to follow what your question.  I think you want to eliminate all `dataid`s that have any `use` values that are NULL or negative.  You can do this with a `having` clause:

```
SELECT ea.dataid,     
       date_trunc('hour', ea.timestamp_localtime)::time AS HOUR, 
       avg(ea.use) AS USE   
FROM dev.egauge_analyze_2 ea
WHERE ea.timestamp_localtime BETWEEN '2012-07-16 00:00:00' AND '2012-08-17 23:59:59'
GROUP BY 1,2
having sum(case when use is null or use < 0 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
ORDER BY 1,2
```

In addition, I removed the `distinct` in the `select` clause, since it is unnecessary (you have a `group by`).  I also gave the table a more readable alias, `ea` instead of the table name.

Comment: Maybe `HAVING avg(ea.use) is not null and avg(ea.use) > 0`? Or just `HAVING avg(ea.use) > 0`.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko . . . I think the explicit comparison to NULL makes the clause clearer about its intention.

Comment: @Gordon thanks for your reply. The above code does not seem to give me the desired output. I'll try to explain a bit more: The output should give me 24 hourly values for each dataid, each of those values should be the average of all the values (USE) that are aggregated in the timestamp manipulations. What I am trying to do is throw away ALL data for a dataid even if one USE value for a given timestamp (the raw data are in minutes level) associated with that dataid is NULL or <=0. Thanks